# Push an R dataframe to SQL as a new table

Tags: r, sql-server, odbc, r-markdown, rnotebook

*I'm trying to make my analysis workflow more efficient connecting my SQL Server Database to R-Studio.*

**What I do now?**

1. I develop my queries using MS SQL Management Studio to extract relevant information for the analysis.
2. I export the query result to a .csv UTF-8 file.
3. I read the file in R-Studio and perform analyses.
4. I export the final dataframe to a .csv UTF-8 file.
5. I use this file to create a table back in SQL Management Studio.

**What am I trying to do?**

I want to create a connection between SQL Server and R-Studio so I can directly import/export my dataframe/table without having these files in my computer.

To do that I have followed these steps:

1. Installed DBI and odbc packages in R.
2. Configured the connection using "ODBC Data Source Connection Administrator"

   - My connection name is "Enterprise" (SQL Server Native Client 10.0)
3. In R-Studio, using the Connection tab, I can seen a list of data sources containing "Enterprise".

   - Choosing "Enterprise" data source create an R object with the name "con" that contains the connection information.
   - At this point I can see all databases in the connection tab.
4. My code for testing in R is the following:

```
---
title: "R Notebook"
output: html_notebook
---
```

````
```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(odbc)
con <- dbConnect(odbc::odbc(), "Enterprise", timeout = 10) ```
````

````
```{sql, connection = con, output.var = "DataFrame"}
SELECT TOP 1000 *
FROM [DB].[dbo].[Table] ```
````

````
Data<-DataFrame[1:100,1:10]
head(Data,11)```

Var1    Var2    Var3    Var4    Var5    Var6    Var7    Var8    Var9    Var10
   A       1    2.4      5.5    13.1    30.8    72.4    170.5   401.6   945.7
   B       2    4.7     11.1    26.1    61.5    144.8   341.1   803.2   1891.5
   C       3    7.1     16.6    39.2    92.3    217.3   511.6   1204.8  2837.2
   D       4    9.4     22.2    52.2    123.0   289.7   682.2   1606.4  3782.9
   E       5    11.8    27.7    65.3    153.8   362.1   852.7   2008.0  4728.6
   F       6    14.1    33.3    78.4    184.5   434.5   1023.2  2409.6  5674.4
   G       7    16.5    38.8    91.4    215.3   506.9   1193.8  2811.2  6620.1
   H       8    18.8    44.4    104.5   246.0   579.4   1364.3  3212.8  7565.8
   I       9    21.2    49.9    117.5   276.8   651.8   1534.9  3614.4  8511.5
   J       10   23.5    55.5    130.6   307.5   724.2   1705.4  4016.0  9457.3
   K       11   25.9    61.0    143.6   338.3   796.6   1875.9  4417.6  10403.0
````

````
```{sql, connection = con}
SELECT * INTO [DB].[dbo].[New_Table]
FROM ?Data```
````

Here I'm using the `?` to indicate that "Data" is an R dataframe object in the SQL Chunk.

```
Error in vapply(values, function(x) { : values must be length 1,
 but FUN(X[[1]]) result is length 100
Failed to execute SQL chunk
```

My guess is I'm doing something wrong in the last chunk.

*What will be the proper way to push "Data" to my data base?*

Comment: You are trying to run a SQL query against local data and *not in the SQL server*. How would you insert data into this table on the console? The only ways I know about (short of the literal SQL code `insert (col1,col2,...) values (...)`) are `DBI::dbWriteTable`, `DBI::dbAppendTable`, and (if your data is somewhere on the server) `insert into tablename select ...`. The latter won't work for you since your data is not in a table the server can see.

Comment: So, perhaps to answer your question, replace your inserting code chunk with an R-code chunk including `DBI::dbInsertTable(con, "New_Table", Data)`.

Comment: (And just to be certain ... unless I'm mistaken, `select ... into ...` will only work if the table does not yet exist; it will not append and will error if the table already exists. Is that your intent?)

Comment: @r2evans This is making perfect sense to me. I have changed my chunk for the following: `dbWriteTable(con, "[DB].[dbo].[New_Table]", Data)` I tried with `dbInsertTable` but It was not recognized. The issue now is I'm getting the following error: `nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:1587: 42000: [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 10.0][SQL Server]CREATE TABLE permission denied in database 'master'.` because is trying to copy the table into the master and is ignoring the path to the DB I have the permission. `"[DB].[dbo].[New_Table]"`

Comment: @r2evans This is the SQL interpretation of the last function: `> dbWriteTable(con, "[DB].[dbo].[New_Table]", Data)
Error: <SQL> 'CREATE TABLE "[DB].[dbo].[New_Table]" (
  "Var1" varchar(255),
  "Var2" FLOAT,
  "Var3" FLOAT,
  "Var4" FLOAT,
  "Var5" FLOAT
)`

Comment: `dbInsertTable` was a typo, glad you saw through that. You need to figure out the "permissions" issue on your own, and perhaps that discussion will guide you into using `create=` and perhaps even `DBI::dbCreateTable(..., temporary=...)` before inserting the data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**How I solved it?**

I was on the right track until I got to the part of pushing my dataframe to the DB. @r2evans pointed out that I was trying to create a table from the server with information that only existed locally with this code:

````
```{sql, connection = con}
SELECT * INTO [DB].[dbo].[New_Table]
FROM ?Data```
````

At this point, I changed the method and tried to pushed the dataframe using r-code:

````
```{r}
dbWriteTable(con, "[DB].[dbo].[New_Table]", Data)```
````

The result was the following error:

> nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:1587: 42000: [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 10.0][SQL Server]CREATE TABLE permission denied in database 'master'.

**The problem here:** I was trying to access to the database I have the permission using `"[DB].[dbo].[New_Table]"`. The `dbWriteTable` function understand this parameter just as a pure name for the table, so I had to find a way to specify the right path to the database.

*I did not find the way to do it using code directly.* **Solution:** I went to the `"ODBC Data Sources (32-bit)"` (Windows APP); and changed the configuration of my connection. The connection I had, was taking the *master* as the default database. I changed it for the database I have the permission. So now I'm using the following code to push the table from R-notebooks:

````
```{r}
dbWriteTable(con, "[R_Test2]", Data, overwrite = T)```
````

*It's working perfectly for what I need.*

If someone know how to specify this path using code, will be good to know. Maybe in the first configuration chunk:

````
```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(odbc)
library(DBI)
con <- dbConnect(odbc::odbc(), "Enterprise", timeout = 10)```
````